# "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" async await when i try to deploy it to aws cloud on nodejs v8.11.4

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

im trying to deploy my project with async await to aws, actually its running in local, but when i start it using npm forever i got an error

```
    async getStock(req, res) {
      ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (rcenter.id/task/routes/stock.js:3:22)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
```

here my stock.js

```
module.exports = {

async getStock(req, res) {

    try {
        let body = req.body;
        let limit = parseInt(req.body.limit);
        let offset = 0;

        let stocks = await Stock.findAndCountAll({});

        let page = req.body.page;

        let pages = Math.ceil(stocks.count / limit)
        offset = limit * (page - 1)


        let stock = await Stock.findAll({
            limit: limit,
            offset: offset,

        });

         //count json data per page
         let key, count = 0;
         for (key in stock) {
             if (stock.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                 count++;
             }
         }
         console.log(count)
        res.send({ "http_code": 200, "status": "success", "code": "SSR001", "message": "get data success", "data": stock,"current_page": page,  "total_pages": pages,"maximum_record":limit, "total_records":count })

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({"http_code": 500, "status": "failed", "code": "SON004","message":"data not found" })
    }
}

 }
```

anything wrong with my stock.js??

note : im using node-v8.11.4, also im using npm forever for running the script

Comment: The syntax is valid. *im using node-v8.11.4* - you likely aren't, this error will occur in Node 7 and lower but not in 8.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of your module is wrong. You've placed a function inside the `module.exports` object but you've not assigned the function to a property.

Your code should be structured like:

```
module.exports = {
    getStock: async function getStock() {...}
};
```

Comment: And I also would suggest to use arrow function as well.

Comment: i think i get same error `getStock: async function getStock(req, res) {}`

Comment: I can't really help any further with the information we've got sorry! The error you received before was definitely due to the structure but beyond that we'd need more information to debug. Are you 100% sure its the same stacktrace?

Comment: Ooh Gosh, the syntax should be `getStock: async function() {...}` or `getStock: async () => {...}` (as I prefer) because the function name will be the key. @RiaAnggraini

Comment: All three ways work, a named function, an anonymous function and arrow functions.

Comment: The syntax in the OP is valid. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions#Async_methods

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone is still having this problem but for some reason the dropdown in AWS Lambda reverted to 6.1* and I never noticed. Fixing this to 8.** fixed my issue.